# Is British English more correct than other modified English languages?

Tags: grammar

Is British English more correct than other forms of English, such as American English? English originated from England, which is in the UK, a.k.a., the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, yes a mouthful. Is it necessary in the US, as I am American, to use British English? Can it be argued as acceptable? Or does British English have no place in countries that have their own form of the language? Thanks for helping.

Comment: This site is not the right place for such questions, because 1) your question is based on false, misinformed premises. You'd be surprised to know how English English (English spoken in England) is not and never was a monolith and how English English has changed, evolved, morphed over the centuries. 2) No English tradition is better than another. I have noticed from your profile page that you might still be receiving your secondary or even primary education. I think there is much to bone up on for a thorough discussion on this topic.

Comment: I dunno, sometimes I feel the Brits absolutely MURDER the American language.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No English is *more correct* than any other.

Long answer:

Language transforms and changes ALL THE TIME. Even in British English, there are many words that are added to and removed from dictionaries *every year*! In *just* Britain alone, the English language slightly differs between different regions. The same happens in every language. They evolve and change depending how people use it.

You may also hear in American English (especially when spoken by many black people), *double negatives* occur. (It's not racist at all by the way. Black people tend to gather and form groups and communities and the way they speak and use English just spread and grow among those communities.) For example: "Ain't nobody got time for that!" is, in traditional English (British and American) quite confusing and may mean something like "Someone has time for that". However, most people would understand that the *double negative* in that case is for emphasis, and the sentence means "Nobody has time for that".

If you look at old English, or even just the common Shakespearean literature (to be honest I haven't read any of them), you'll likely find the language hard to understand with a lot of words not used today. Languages evolve all the time and nothing is always right or always wrong in terms of grammar and vocabulary.

You may even find in some dictionaries (may be as a joke) a word often used by a lot of people: "literally". Some may have the definition: "literally meas not literally" which sounds crazy, but people are using the word like that so much that it just becomes so. It's a pretty contradictory topic of discussion but it goes to show that words can often suddenly change meaning, sometimes in ridiculous ways.

American English is just an evolved and branched form of British English. Same goes for Canadian, Australian, etc.